# php DOMDocument createTextNode from blob field(text) not showing data

Tags: php, xml, blob

I am trying to create XML using DOMDocument from database table. All field types are showing in XML node except BLOB Type.
Below what I did:

```
$rs = ibase_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$coln = ibase_num_fields($rs);
$fieldnames = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $coln; $i++) {
    $col_info = ibase_field_info($rs, $i);
    $fieldnames[] = array('name' => $col_info['name'], 'type' => $col_info['type']);
}

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$root = $doc->createElement('FA_ARTIKEL');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($sth, IBASE_TEXT)) {
    $title = $doc->createElement('RECORD');
    $title = $root->appendChild($title);

    $text = $doc->createTextNode('');
    $text = $title->appendChild($text);
    foreach ($fieldnames as $value) {
        switch ($value['type']) {
            case 'VARCHAR':
                $rtitle = $doc->createElement($value['name']);
                $rtitle = $title->appendChild($rtitle);

                $rtext = $doc->createTextNode($row->$value['name']);
                $rtext = $rtitle->appendChild($rtext);
                break;

            case 'BLOB':
                $rbtitle = $doc->createElement($value['name']);
                $rbtitle = $title->appendChild($rbtitle);

                $rbtext = $doc->createTextNode($row->$value['name']);
                $rbtext = $rbtitle->appendChild($rbtext);
                break;

            default:
                if ($row->$value['name']) {
                    $rtitle = $doc->createElement($value['name']);
                    $rtitle = $title->appendChild($rtitle);

                    $rtext = $doc->createTextNode($row->$value['name']);
                    $rtext = $rtitle->appendChild($rtext);
                } else {
                    $rtitle = $doc->createElement($value['name']);
                    $rtitle = $title->appendChild($rtitle);

                    $rtext = $doc->createTextNode('0');
                    $rtext = $rtitle->appendChild($rtext);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $doc->saveXML() . "\n";
ibase_free_result($sth);
ibase_close($dbh);
```

I tried with SimpleXMLElement also but it also failed. What I am missing?
My Database is Firebird and I set BLOB fields as

```
BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 16384
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPs DOMDocument expects UTF-8 strings. It is possible that the blob contains control characters/invalid unicode sequences. Try to put the data that breaks the XML into a variable and reduce your problem to the absolute minimum.

```
$blobData = $record['blobField'];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('foo'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($blobData));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

This way you can see if the blob data is really the problem or merely a symptom.

If the BLOB contains binary data you will need to convert it into a TEXT format. Atom feeds for example urlencode binary data that they want to embed. In this you will need to decode the value in the reading program.